# HTML Button Linking to Another Page

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to link a "Sign In" button to another page called mainpage.html.

```
  <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>Transport Login Form</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="loginBox">
            <img src="user.png" class="user">
            <h2>Login To Decryption 1.0</h2>
            <form>
                <p>Email</p>
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Email">
                <p>Password</p>
                <input type="password" name="" placeholder=".....">
                <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
                <a href="#">Forget Password</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

At the input type "submit" and value="Sign In", I am trying to get the "Sign In" button to link to another page I have, called mainpage.html.

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign In">
```

I have tried various ways to get the button to work, but everything has failed.

Comment: Either use an anchor, e.g. `<a href="mainpage.html">...` without the form, or add an action to your form, e.g. `<form action="mainpage.html...`. A submit button does just that, submits your form. And in your case since you have no action it will simply post back to itself and reload the page.

Comment: See this question for a few other methods: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Comment: Please read about http://devdocs.io/html/element/form for information on how forms work.

Comment: This is what you need :`<form method="post" action="http://www.google.com">`

Answer (score 0):

Because you need read about POST/GET if you want create working submit button with redirect.
But if you need simple example without working form — use `<a href="linktopage.html">`

Comment: Above the submit button, I added this: <a href="http://google.com" class="btn btn-default">Go to Google</a>, which created a simple link and that worked fine. However, when trying to get the actual Submit button to direct me to google, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onclick like that `<input type="submit" onclick="location.href='mainpage.htm';" value="Sign In" />`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments already, and assuming that you are just designing the website for now, change the `<form>` line to this:

```
<form method="get" action="mainpage.html">
```

It will enable your submit button to redirect to the specified link.